# Run Angular from inside docker container

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, development-environment

I want to have a Docker container with image of the Angular application **to be served from inside**. So user could pull the image, run the application and start developing conveniently.

My current Dockerfile is:

```
FROM node:20.11.0-alpine

COPY . /ng17/

WORKDIR /ng17

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

RUN npm install

CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Docker runs my app on 4201 port and it's fine. Still, the problem is that code is not being compiled realtime like if I would "ng serve" regularly w/o docker. **I believe "ng serving" from inside the container resolves it**.

My docker flow is basic:

```bash
docker build -t ng17:0.1 .
docker run -d -p 4201:4200 ng17:0.1
```

I suspect the problem somewhere around `CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]` and `docker run -d -p 4201:4200 ng17:0.1`, but can't figure this out alone. My humble Docker experience tells me the answer connected with `exec`, `bash` etc.

ps. I'm learning Docker's key principles and specially to understand how handy it can be in my Frontend development. Next I am to go with docker-compose, fix some local backend etc. Any strategies, pros and cons, setups and just advices of this topic are very appreciated.

Comment: How are you editing the source files? Are the files edited in code also changing in the container? Are you mounting a volume or copying the files?

Comment: @Jeppe, I'm editing from IDE WebStorm. The files are not being changed, because I'm making docker build before, so as I understand that is "static". I'm not mounting the volume, neither copying the files (except of the commands of dockerfile).

Comment: Well that's why it's not happening. Either mount the working directory so the CLI (inside the container) sees the changes, or ng build then serve the results in a multi-stage build if you want a container to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is that code is not being compiled realtime like if I would "ng serve" regularly w/o docker.

This is exactly expected in you current workflow as you are copying files into Docker image once during `docker build`, exactly one line `COPY . /ng17/`

I suggest you to build simple image by using

```
FROM node:20.11.0-alpine

WORKDIR /work

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

CMD npm install && ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

You need only angular CLI installed during build, rest will be provided during starting container as you want real-time update

Of course to build it use the same command that you have already: `docker build -t ng17:0.1 .`

To start a container use a little bit longer command

```bash
docker run --init --rm -t --net host -v $PWD:/work:rw -u $(id -u):$(id -g) ng17:0.1
```

- Instead of using port mapping (`-p 4201:4200`), I think(for development) simpler is using `--net host` but it's about preferences both will work.
- `--rm` is just to remove container when it exits as it's not needed, all our changes are mount using `-v`, so we don't care about other changes inside container and it keeps docker containers cleaner (if you type `docker ps -a` without cleaning old containers list might be long and just eat your disk space)
- Angular `ng serve` as I tested doesn't work well with Ctrl+C to stop it, quick fix for it is use `--init` (it can used with any application that is not correctly handling signals)
- `-t` this added `tty` to running container, so when `npm install` packages you will see progress, without this you might think nothing going on as progress bar will not appear
- I removed `-d` as like to have open console open somewhere and see logs, without this when your angular app fails to compile you have to use `docker log $CONTAINER_NAME` to see what went wrong, it makes life harder. Also when you are done with work just pres Ctrl+C in that console and container exits and everything is cleaned up
- Next `-v $PWD:/work:rw` it will mount your current working directory into running container and this what makes changes in your IDE instantly visible by the container to `ng serve` can reload app. I also added `:rw` as all changes made by the container are visible on the host, mostly because when `npm install` install packages that we want to persist between container restarts
- Last parameter is `-u $(id -u):$(id -g)`, by default most Docker images run as `root` but when you local user(on host machine) is in 99% cases different so, it will end up that some files are owned by your local user and rest(mostly `node_modules`) by the `root` and this makes it harder to deleted when you have to, so force same user in the container as is used in the host machine

---

All this `docker run` can be changed to `docker-compose`, so you will be able to setup everything by shorter command: `docker-compose up`

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  frontend:
    build: .
    init: true
    tty: true
    user: "${UID:-1000}:${GID:-1000}"
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
    - $PWD:/work:rw
```

Unfortunately this version has harder to makes correct user id inside the container, so I default it to `1000` that is in many cases correct, you can manually change it to correct value or start `docker-compose` using

```bash
UID=$(id -u) GID=$(id -g) docker-compose up
```

**Note**: If you have latest docker version you can use `docker compose` instead of `docker-compose` command (space instead of dash(`-`))